# Eclipse RCP Export product wizard fails because of conflicting bundles?

Tags: export, eclipse-rcp, product

I am using Eclipse Galileo. I am learning Eclipse RCP and doing some examples from a book. Recently my Eclipse Galileo updated and some updated bundles arrived. I have the following problem which totally prevents me from exporting an Eclipse RCP product via the wizard. While exporting a product I get the following error:

[alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/1091/eclipseexportproduct.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/1091/eclipseexportproduct.png)

I don't understand how can I fix it..

PS. I fully read the OSGi R4 specification (v 4.1) and some of the compendium chapters. I am also familiar with Equinox since I read another book on pure OSGi development.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I have found from your error message is [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/pde-dev/msg01332.html), with this answer:

> Is your target defined as an "installation" of `${eclipse_home}`?
>   In this case the p2 profile is queried to determine what bundles are present in your host.
>   I would only expect one version of a bundle to be installed in your host.

That is why some PDE development settings would advise to remove that `${eclipse_home}` from the location of the runtime environment. See for instance [Corona](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Corona/GettingStarted/Dev)

> Step 5: Define Workspace Target Platform
>   Each Plug-in Development Workspace can be configured for a specific target platform.
>
> - Open the team.corona/runtime/CoronaDevelopmentRuntime.target file
> - In Location, remove the two items:

```
${eclipse_home}
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5
```

> - Click Add
> - Select Directory and click Next
> - In Location browse to team.corona\runtime\generated\corona\eclipse
> - Click Finish
> - Click on Set as Target Platform link on the Top Right corner.
> - Save the file and close it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this a common problem? From your comments I understood that I have to create "my own" platform having needed bundles in `<my platform>/plugins`. And then specify directory `<my platform>` as the Directory (instead of Installation) in the Target Content section of the Target Platform preferences page.

Right?

Comment: @Grigory: something like that (I am not too familiar in RCP platform deployment). Even if it is not *exactly* the same issue, it illustrates the fact the target considers having the OSGi plugin already installed, hence the error message. My post was an example of why it could believe that, and how to remove one potential cause.

Comment: @VonC: downloading the Eclipse RCP base distr for linux and specifying it as the Target platform solved the problem. Thanks.

I am saying about this download for example http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.1-200909170800/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-RCP-3.5.1-linux-gtk.tar.gz